# How does the apache_beam.io.kinesis.ReadDataFromKinesis() work

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I am attempting to use `apache_beam.io.kinesis.ReadDataFromKinesis` in my pipeline, but I keep getting the following error message:

```
org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.apache.beam.sdk.io.kinesis.ShardReadersPool.getLatestRecordTimestamp()" because "this.shardReadersPool" is null.
```

What could be causing this issue and how can I resolve it?